# having trouble scraping links with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

Python student here, learning the basics of web scraping. Trying to pull the links from this bs4 element that I've scraped from a webpage.

```py
house = committee[0].find_all("li")
house
```

Result:

```
[<li><a href="/committee/house-agriculture/hsag00">Agriculture</a></li>,
<li><a href="/committee/house-appropriations/hsap00">Appropriations</a></li>,
<li><a href="/committee/house-armed-services/hsas00">Armed Services</a></li>,
<li><a href="/committee/house-budget/hsbu00">Budget</a></li>,
<li><a href="/committee/house-education-and-labor/hsed00">Education and ... ]
```

So when I try to pull out the links I'm using list comprehension:

```py
links_h = [link.get(" href")for link in house]
links_h
```

But instead of returning the links, it's returning this:

```py
[None,
None,
None,
None,
None]
```

Not sure if I need to do something different because these are internal links... I'm just kind of lost. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of `li` tags which have no `href` attribute - the `href` attribute is of the `a` tags, which are wrapped as list items.

You can either get the `href`s like this:

```
links_h = [link.find('a').get("href")for link in house if link.find('a')]
```

**OR** you can try getting the a tags directly as

```
house = committee[0].select("li > a")
```

so that the `[link.get("href")for link in house]` part works.